# Are interested and interesting related or different

Tags: word-usage

I just wanted to know because a lot of people are saying they are different some are saying they are related

Comment: All 3 answers provide useful insights for you. The way Stack Exchange works, answers should be authoritative. Look through them and check the dictionary links, weigh the logic, etc. Learn what you can from each, up-vote those you think are useful, down-vote those (if any) you think are useless, and award whichever you think best the green tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're related.  They're both participles of the verb "[to interest](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interest?s=t)."

"[Interested](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interested?s=t)" is the past participle of the verb "to interest" and is often used as an adjective.

"[Interesting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interesting?s=t)" is the present participle of the verb "to interest" and is also often used as an adjective, albeit with different effect.

The adjectival difference between "interested" and "interesting" is "interested" describes one as having interest, one who something interests, whereas "interesting" describes what or who it is that elicits interest (i.e., What the interested person is interested in is what is interesting.).

Answer (score 3):

**interested v. interesting**   [allearsenglish](https://www.allearsenglish.com/aee-185-interested-interesting-find-difference/)

Related yes, but with different meanings.

> When talking about yourself or your feelings, use the –ed ending.  “I
>   am **interested** in music.”
>       When talking about others or something outside yourself, use the –ing ending.  “That music is **interesting**.”

And more at Allearsenglish.com

Comment: same root, different meanings in usage

Comment: @RaychatuS There is a *sizable* difference between the two.

Comment: @RaychatuS As Ibf said, they have the same root, but semantically, they mean two completely different things.

Answer (score 2):

Putting aside the grammatical difference, the semantic difference is as follows: *Interested* is an adjective meaning "concerned, affected; having an interest, concern, or share in something.” *Interesting* is also an adjective but it means "arousing interest." Therefore, one is interested *in* something, and usually this thing will be *interesting*.

See [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interested) for *interested* and [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interesting) for *interesting*.